# What are some apps/software examples where users can create content, share content, and/or pull content from?

Tags: applications, content-management, software

Looking for a few examples of the question above. One sample is Gmail where the user can create mail, share, and pull from (attachments).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm reading your question correctly, but there are a ton of things like this. Pretty much all social media platforms are built on this concept.

They are built on user created content that is shared and can have content pulled from. Here are a few examples:

**Wordpress** - users create blog posts, they can include images or files (other content formats that can be 'pulled'), they publish them (share them). Other users can add content (comments), save copy or attachements (pull content), and repost or share.

**Twitter, Facebook, Instagram etc** - users can create content, they can share content on these platforms, and the content can be pulled from them (downloaded, through APIs, etc).

**Youtube** - Users create videos, they share them, and in someways they can be pulled (again, either as embeded videos in other websites, or downloaded).

I'm not sure this is the anser that you want, because there are so many examples, and much of the web is built on this idea - and not just websites, but as you say apps/software. All of my above examples are web apps, or mobile apps.

This is such a broad question, you might want to help us out with some more info, like what you want this information for?